# What does it mean to say that Huobi "self-match" trades?

Tags: exchanges, fraud

A [reddit post](http://www.reddit.com/r/Bitcoin/comments/1v9qqx/huobi_can_we_cut_the_bullshit_already/) claims that Huobi is faking trade volume by "self-matching" trades.

What does it mean to say that Huobi "self-match" trades?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It basically means that the exchange is showing false volume on their site.

Here is how:

- Exchange inserts order to buy 1 btc @500USD/BTC
- Exchange inserts order to sell 1 btc @500USD/BTC
- Orders match and the exchange's trade volume has increased by 1btc.

But actually, no real trade has occurred. They artificially updated their records to attract more traders.

This would be harshly penalized if it was done by a regulated exchange.

Comment: So how likely is it that Huobi is doing as such?

Comment: It's impossible to say for sure.